# XPath: Trying to filter based on multiple child nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<doc>
  <target>
    <name>V1</name>
    <value>3</value>
    <more>foo</more>
  </target>
  <target>
    <name>V3</name>
    <value>5</value>
    <more>bar</more>
  </target>
  <var>
    <name>V1</name>
    <value>3</value>
  </var>
  <var>
    <name>V2</name>
    <value>3</value>
  </var>
</doc>
```

I want an XPath query that returns all `target` nodes where there exists a `var` node with whose `name` and `value` nodes match those specified in the target.  In the example above, there should be no matches.

My attempts at a query look something like this:

```
//target[//var/name=name and //var/value=value]
```

This query returns the first `target` node because there exists a variable `V1`, and there exists a variable whose value is `3`.  But this is not what I am after; I only want matches where the name *and* the value of the same variable match the target.

I'm using XPath 1.0, so techniques to accomplish this with that version would be most helpful.

*Note: Question updated to revise sample XML.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath 1.0 is not relationally complete (see https://www.rjerz.com/c/infosys/support/Codd-Relational_Completeness_Article.pdf) which means that not all join queries can be expressed, and I think this is one that can't. The limitation arises because XPath 1.0 has no range variables.

In XPath 2.0 it's easy:

```
//target[some $v in //var satisfies name=$v/name and value=$v/value]
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but kind of what I was expecting.  Thanks for response.

Answer (score -1):

If `doc` has multiple `var` nodes but one `target` only you can try

```
//doc[var[name=preceding-sibling::target/name and value=preceding-sibling::target/value]]/target
```

Comment: But the requirement to find "all target nodes" suggests that there might be several.

Comment: @MichaelKay is correct, I only have a single target in my simplified example but in my actual data there are several.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @MichaelKay "all target nodes"  might also mean that there are multiple `doc` nodes with single `target` child, so I considered this particular case

Answer (score -1):

Not sure you can do exactly what you want with xpath 1.0 but you can sort of fake it by using the text of the `<var>` nodes to compare to that of `<target>`. So

```
//target[normalize-space(.)=//var/normalize-space(.)]
```

should do it: it will show no match with your sample xml. If you change the `<name>` value in the last `<var>` to `V1` it should show one match.

Comment: XPath 1.0 doesn't allow a function call to appear after the "/" operator. The OP asked for a 1.0 solution.

Comment: I'm all for faking it, but unfortunately the target and var nodes in my actual XML data have other children whose names/values won't line up.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @3rady You should edit your question and modify the sample xml to more close resemble the actual xml. It can make  a difference in the answer.

Comment: @JackFleeting - I updated the question per your recommendation.  I tried to make the sample XML as simple as possible to illustrate my question, but I can see how it may have ended up *too* simple.

Comment: @3rady I see, but you have already accepted an answer (to the previous version of the question, I assume). You should probably reverse the edit and post a new question.